# How to be able to edit files under "Application Support" without saving as a dupe

Tags: finder, permission

So as a person that enjoys (sometimes) making weird resource packs in Minecraft, I find it inconvenient to grab the resource pack I'm working on out of the folder, then put it back in. The reason why I do this is because of this error in Preview while editing:

> The original File can't be changed, so a duplicate with your changes has been created.

This error is annoying, keep in mind that my Minecraft/resourcepacks directory is under my ~/library/Application Support/ folder, which can probably explain why macOS wants to save the items as a dupe. But I want to create an override for my Minecraft resourcepacks folder instead of having to take the folder out to edit it. Is there a way to edit it?

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by adding saveas back to your dropdowns.

See:
https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-software/save-as-mac-3680485/

The deletion of saveas... is ridiculous.  You then should be able to save the file with a different name.

Robert